# Application error: Can't do regex matching on object

Tags: ios, xml, xcode, search, nspredicate

I parse XML and I have search bar.  When I try search, I get this error:

> Can't do regex matching on object `<List: 0x888de20>`.

I think problem is here:

```
- (void) searchTableView 
{
    [filteredList superclass];
    filteredList = nil;

    filteredList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:app.listArray];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF like[c] %@",[NSString  stringWithFormat:@"%@*",search.text]];
    [filteredList filterUsingPredicate:predicate]; 
}
```

I am a beginner in Xcode.

Here is all my MasterViewController Class:

```
@implementation MasterViewController
@synthesize app;
@synthesize detailViewController = _detailViewController;
@synthesize theList;
@synthesize filteredList;
@synthesize search;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    app = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    filteredList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:app.listArray];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    //return [app.listArray count];
    return [filteredList count];
}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }
    theList = [app.listArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = theList.znacka;
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    return cell;
}
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{

    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

- (void) searchTableView
{
    [filteredList superclass];
    filteredList = nil;

    filteredList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:app.listArray];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"count=%d",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@*",search.text]];
    [filteredList filterUsingPredicate:predicate];


}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    DetailViewController *detailView = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];

    theList = [app.listArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    detailView.theList = theList;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailView animated:YES];
}
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    [self searchTableView];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [self searchTableView];
    [search resignFirstResponder];
}
@end
```

I have searchbar in the MasterViewController.xib. There, I have my five items (theList.znacka) from XML and now I need search at these items.

Comment: Could you please get a little bit mor specific or provide more code? What does the XML parsing have to do with the actual problem?

Comment: Thx for your comment, I add all my class MasterViewController. I can add some other informations or code, if you need it ;). I hope, you can help me, because I dont know what is bad :(. And sorry for my english skill :D

Comment: Any idea how to help me pls? thx

Comment: I'm sorry, I just reviewed your question and noticed that it could be improved to help someone experienced in iOS to understand it. I fear you just have to wait.